# Finding a homography in $\hat {\Bbb {C}} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_2,z_3,z_4$ be distinct points of $\hat{\Bbb{C}}$. Show that there exists a unique homography $T:\hat{\Bbb{C}} \to \hat{\Bbb{C}}$ of the form $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$ such that: $T(z_2)=0$,$T(z_3)=1$,$T(z_4)=\infty$

Ok, so Im having some problems in defining my homography, In the book I'm reading, **Complex Analysis, Lars Ahlfors** he simply states the formula for such transformation, without the procedure. So my naiv way to try to solve it is replacing $z_2, z_3$ and $z_4$ and trying to find the corresponding values of $a, b, c$ and $d$. But of course, I only have three equations and four unknowns, so I don't think that is the way to solve it. (I have similar exercises and I assume there is a similar procedure for each.) How should I encounter this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Am I missing something? This is a homography, how can you except this to be a *linear* transformation?

Comment: It is indeed a homography. I didn't know the word in english and in the book they just say its a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a comment but I do not yet have enough reputation to do so.

The most important thing to note is that for any non-zero complex number $\lambda$,
$$
\frac{a z + b}{cz + d} = \frac{\lambda a z + \lambda b}{\lambda c z + \lambda d}.
$$
As such, you may assume without loss of generality that $ad - bc =1$. This then gives you four equations in four unknowns which can be solved explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this kind of equation can be recovered from the nullity of a well chosen determinant.

If $y = T(x)$ then $cxy+dy-ax-b = 0$, so the graph of an homography is given by a linear combination between $1,x,y$ and $xy$.

As a result, as long as everyone stays in $\Bbb C$, four pairs $(x_1,y_1) \ldots (x_4,y_4)$ are on the graph of a single homography if the determinant

$ \left| \begin{array}{} 1 & x_1 & y_1 & x_1 y_1 \\
1 & x_2 & y_2 & x_2 y_2 \\
1 & x_3 & y_3 & x_3 y_3 \\
1 & x_4 & y_4 & x_4 y_4 \end{array} \right|$

is zero.

In particular if you are given $3$ points, you can plug in their coordinates, then develop the determinant along the last line, and the equation of the homography in terms of $x_4$ and $y_4$ will fall out of it.

To get the same result in $\hat {\Bbb C}$, replace $(x_i,y_i)$ with projective coordinates $(x_i/s_i, y_i/t_i)$ and each line $(1,x_i,y_i,x_iy_i)$ with the homogeneous $(s_it_i, x_it_i, s_iy_i, x_iy_i)$

---

If you end up with $a=b=c=d=0$ then it means that the first $3$ lines are linearly dependant, which should imply that two pairs are the same or they all share a coordinate.

If you end up on some linear combination with $ad-bc = 0$, then the corresponding equation can be factored into two linear equations $(a'+b'x)(c'+d'y) = 0$ so the graph is just the reunion of two lines and isn't even the graph of a function.
It is pretty clear that among any $3$ points from the graph, there are two who share their $x$ or $y$ coordinate, so this can't happen if the $(x_i)$ are pairwise distinct as well as the $(y_i)$.

Comment: I can't see how making the determinant equal to zero implies that the four coordinate points are in the same homography. Nevertheless, by developing the determinant, im getting $\infty - \infty $ indeterminacies which are leading me nowhere.

Comment: there exists nonzero $a,b,c,d$ making all $4$ equations true if and only if there exists nonzero $a,b,c,d$ in the kernel of the matrix. And that kernel is nontrivial if and only if the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the 3 points and clear everything, you'll see that everything is multiplied by either a, b, c or d, so you can cancel it. The procedure would be:

$T(z_{2})=\frac{az_{2} + b}{cz_{2} + d} = 0$. For this, you need that b=$-az_{2}$.

$T(z_{4})=\frac{az_{4} -az_{2}}{cz_{4} + d} = \infty$. For this, you need that $cz_{4}+d=0$ so $d = -cz_{4}$.

$T(z_{3}) = \frac{az_{3} - az_{2}}{cz_{3} - cz_{4}} = 1 \Rightarrow a(z_{3}-z_{2}) = c(z_{3}-z_{4}) \Rightarrow a=c\frac{z_{3}-z_{4}}{z_{3}-z_{2}}$.

Finally

$T(z)=\frac{c\frac{z_{3}-z_{4}}{z_{3}-z_{2}}(z - z_{2})}{c(z-z_{4})}$

So you can cancel c and it remains

$T(z)=\frac{\frac{z_{3}-z_{4}}{z_{3}-z_{2}}(z - z_{2})}{z-z_{4}}$

You can then accomodate it better, but this defines the homography